# Display icons only on mask images

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, if-statement

There are two types of images in our json files....

1.Mask images

- Which have Transparent background as below :

[image]

2.Background images :

- Any normal images

Right now I am displaying Icons on all images as in below codepens....

Icons on **Mask images** : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/aMPvam

[image]

Icons on **Background images** : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/jJXbej

[image]

Sample Json for Mask image :

```
"layers" : [
            {             
              "src" : "image1.png",              
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
```

Sample Json for Background images :

```
"layers" : [
            {             
              "src" : "image2.png",              
              "name" : "bg_image"
            },
```

**Requirement** :

but i want to display icons only on Mask images but not on Background images....

So I used below code , but that did't helped me :

```
if (layer.name == mask_image_1) 
{                       
imageUrl: imageUrl, 
}
```

name of mask images will be start with "**mask_**" in JSON

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/As37YCl.png";

let jsonData = {  
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 788,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "height" : 788,
          "src" : "lRtZPoj.jpg",
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 940,
          "type" : "image",
          "name" : "bg_image"
        }        
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 940,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "fb_post_5"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // upload image onclick

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
  // filtering out non-canvas clicks
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

  // getting absolute points relative to container
  const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
  const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

  const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
  // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
  $canvasList.parent().css({zIndex: 0});

  $canvasList.filter(function () { // filtering only applicable canvases
    const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect()
    return (
      absX >= bbox.left && absX <= bbox.left + bbox.width &&
      absY >= bbox.top && absY <= bbox.top + bbox.height)
  }).each(function () { // checking white in a click position
    const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
    const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
    const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
      $(this).parent().css({zIndex: 2})
      target = this.id;
      console.log(target);
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#fileup').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  })
});
 
 
    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

     function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                    src,
                    x,
                    y
                } of arr) {
                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                  imageUrl: imageUrl,
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
                };
                counter++;
    // get the text
    
            }
drawText(data);
        }

json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready


// extempl code - get the text

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

$('.container').append(
            '<div class="txtContainer" ' +
            'style="' +
   'text-align: ' + layer.justification + '; ' +
   'font-family: ' + layer.font + '; ' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
   'width:' + layer.width + 'px; ' +
            'color: ' + layer.color.replace(/^0x/, '#') + '; ' +      
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
             'height:' + layer.height + 'px;' +
            '">' +
            layer.text +
            '</div>');
    }

}
// extempl code end 



// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        updateStyle();
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        function updateStyle() 
  {      
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            image = new Image();
            image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                div.css({
                    "width": image.width,
                    "height": image.height
                });
                img = new Image();
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            };
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
             console.log("load");
            //if (img)
               // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        function loadMaskImage(imageUrl) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.container img {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:250px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: A simple json object and by removing the process of entire json object will help to identify the root cause easily. Can you make a simple code and update it in codepen?

Comment: @Harshana Updated the json file.....

Comment: You can use indexOf to check if term exists in a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf.  Or if you can edit your JSON why not add other attribuite for the Mask images? mask: true

Comment: @keypaul can you please tell which term you are referring here ?

Comment: Yournamevalue.indexOf('mask_'). There're a lot of option to check substring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: @keypaul i cant edit json files as client instructed the same, because we are generating 1000's of json files in a automated way....

Comment: @vickeycolors Just added my answer. please check.

Comment: The condizioni is in the link, this: if(yournamevalue.indexOf('mask_') !== -1){}

Comment: @keypaul if i try like `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') == 0)` , `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') !== -1)` ,  `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') >= 0)` then icons `don't display` on both images as in [codepen1](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wOOWPr) , when i try like `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') == -1)` , then icons `display` on both images as in [codepen2](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ywwaoB)......

Comment: @keypaul no, actually if you use same code in https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ywwaoB , than icons still display , but i dont want icons for those images in codepen.....

Comment: @keypaul same code should work for both the cases..... https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wOOWPr & https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wOOWPr

Comment: But why you use 'mask_ '  with space? Try removing space. name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1

Comment: @keypaul still the same result if i use `name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 `...... here is https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/EMMbBx

Comment: I see in row 223 name.indexOf('mask_') == -1 It should be name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 here your fork https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRRYXX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190623/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-keypaul).

Comment: So like i said in mine previous comments worked

Comment: can you please join chat : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190623/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-keypaul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define new property `name` for `json(data)` function and then you can make condition like.

```
if(name.indexOf('bg_image') == -1){
   var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
}else{
   var imageUrl1 = '';
}
```

Here I have updated full code :

```js
var target;
    var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/As37YCl.png";

    let jsonData = {
        "layers" : [
            {
                "x" : 0,
                "height" : 788,
                "layers" : [
                    {
                        "x" : 0,
                        "height" : 788,
                        "src" : "lRtZPoj.jpg",
                        "y" : 0,
                        "width" : 940,
                        "type" : "image",
                        "name" : "bg_image"
                    }
                ],
                "y" : 0,
                "width" : 940,
                "type" : "group",
                "name" : "fb_post_5"
            }
        ]
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // upload image onclick

        $('.container').click(function(e) {
            // filtering out non-canvas clicks
            if (e.target.tagName !== 'CANVAS') return;

            // getting absolute points relative to container
            const absX = e.offsetX + e.target.parentNode.offsetLeft + e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
            const absY = e.offsetY + e.target.parentNode.offsetTop + e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

            const $canvasList = $(this).find('canvas');
            // moving all canvas parents on the same z-index
            $canvasList.parent().css({zIndex: 0});

            $canvasList.filter(function () { // filtering only applicable canvases
                const bbox = this.getBoundingClientRect()
                return (
                    absX >= bbox.left && absX <= bbox.left + bbox.width &&
                    absY >= bbox.top && absY <= bbox.top + bbox.height)
            }).each(function () { // checking white in a click position
                const x = absX - this.parentNode.offsetLeft - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
                const y = absY - this.parentNode.offsetTop - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;
                const pixel = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    $(this).parent().css({zIndex: 2})
                    target = this.id;
                    console.log(target);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        $('#fileup').click();
                    }, 20);
                }
            })
        });


        function getAllSrc(layers) {
            let arr = [];
            layers.forEach(layer => {
                if (layer.src) {
                    arr.push({
                        src: layer.src,
                        x: layer.x,
                        y: layer.y,
                        name: layer.name
                    });
                } else if (layer.layers) {
                    let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                    if (newArr.length > 0) {
                        newArr.forEach(({
                                            src,
                                            x,
                                            y,
                                            name
                                        }) => {
                            arr.push({
                                src,
                                x: (layer.x + x),
                                y: (layer.y + y),
                                name: (name)
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            return arr;
        }

        function json(data)

        {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;

            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

            let layer1 = data.layers;
            width = layer1[0].width;
            height = layer1[0].height;
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
                $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
                if(name.indexOf('bg_image') == -1){
                    var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
                }else{
                    var imageUrl1 = '';
                }
                var mask = $(".container").mask({
                    imageUrl: imageUrl1,
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
                };
                counter++;
                // get the text

            }
            drawText(data);
        }

        json(jsonData);
    }); // end of document ready


    // extempl code - get the text

    const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

    function drawText(layer) {

        if (layer.type === 'image') return;

        if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
            return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
        }

        if (layer.type === 'text') {
            const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

            if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
                fonts.push(url);
                $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                    "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                    "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                    "}");
            }

            $('.container').append(
                '<div class="txtContainer" ' +
                'style="' +
                'text-align: ' + layer.justification + '; ' +
                'font-family: ' + layer.font + '; ' +
                'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
                'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
                'width:' + layer.width + 'px; ' +
                'color: ' + layer.color.replace(/^0x/, '#') + '; ' +
                'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
                'height:' + layer.height + 'px;' +
                '">' +
                layer.text +
                '</div>');
        }

    }
    // extempl code end



    // jq plugin

    (function($) {
        var JQmasks = [];
        $.fn.mask = function(options) {
            // This is the easiest way to have default options.
            var settings = $.extend({
                // These are the defaults.
                maskImageUrl: undefined,
                imageUrl: undefined,
                scale: 1,
                id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
                x: 0, // image start position
                y: 0, // image start position
                onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            }, options);


            var container = $(this);

            let prevX = 0,
                prevY = 0,
                draggable = false,
                img,
                canvas,
                context,
                image,
                timeout,
                initImage = false,
                startX = settings.x,
                startY = settings.y,
                div;

            container.mousePosition = function(event) {
                return {
                    x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                    y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
                };
            }

            container.selected = function(ev) {
                var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
                var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                    var offset = $(this).offset()
                    var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                    var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                    var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                    return d[0] > 0
                });

                JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                    var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                    if (el.id == id)
                        el.item.enable();
                    else el.item.disable();
                });
            };

            container.enable = function() {
                draggable = true;
                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                div.css({
                    "z-index": 2
                });
            }

            container.disable = function() {
                draggable = false;
                $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
                div.css({
                    "z-index": 1
                });
            }

            container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
                if (evt.target.getContext) {
                    var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                    $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                    container.selected(evt);
                    prevX = evt.clientX;
                    prevY = evt.clientY;
                    var img = new Image();
                    evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                    evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

                }
            };

            container.getImagePosition = function() {
                return {
                    x: settings.x,
                    y: settings.y,
                    scale: settings.scale
                };
            };

            container.onDragOver = function(evt) {

                if (evt.target.getContext) {
                    var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                        if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                            var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                            var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                            if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                                return; // position has not changed
                            settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                            settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                            prevX = evt.clientX;
                            prevY = evt.clientY;
                            updateStyle();
                        }
                    } else {
                        evt.stopPropagation();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };

            function updateStyle()
            {
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    img = new Image();
                    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                    img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                    img.onload = function() {
                        settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                        settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                        context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                        initImage = false;
                    };
                };
            };

            // change the draggable image
            container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
                console.log("load");
                //if (img)
                // img.remove();
                // reset the code.
                settings.y = startY;
                settings.x = startX;
                prevX = prevY = 0;
                settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
                initImage = true;
                updateStyle();
            };

            // change the masked Image
            function loadMaskImage(imageUrl) {
                canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
                canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
                settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
                div = $("<div/>", {
                    "class": "masked-img"
                }).append(canvas);

                // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
                div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                    if (event.handled === false) return;
                    event.handled = true;
                    container.onDragStart(event);
                });

                div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                    if (event.handled === false) return;
                    event.handled = true;
                    container.selected(event);
                });

                div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
                container.append(div);
                if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                    settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
                container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
            };
            loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
            JQmasks.push({
                item: container,
                id: settings.id
            })
            return container;
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
            background: gold;
            position: relative;

        }

        .container img {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:250px;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            margin:auto;
            z-index:999;
        }

        .masked-img {
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, if we give condition for `('bg_image') == -1`, than it will work fine, instead can we give condition for `mask_` means icons should display only for these types : `mask_image_1 , mask_image_2 , mask_pic_1 , mask_pic_2`

Comment: @vickeycolors yes, we can you just need to reverse the condition `('mask_ ') !== -1`

Comment: @vickeycolors if it works for you, can you please accept  and upvote my answer

Comment: is this correct ? `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ')! == -1)`

Comment: @vickeycolors not correct , there is space. Use like `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') !== -1)` or  `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') == 0)` or  `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') >= 0)`

Comment: I tired for json file which have `"name" : "mask_image_1"`, but still icons are not displaying, please check : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wOOWPr

Comment: Okay, I Will check and let you know

Comment: @vickeycolors use condition like `if(name.indexOf('mask_ ') == -1){` it is working please check : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzzRbb

Comment: okay, in that case it will display icons here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ywwaoB

Comment: @vickeycolors for that you have to add new parameter in json for bgImage and check condition. i have implement code at : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRRMvG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190618/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-bhavin-solanki).

Comment: if there is a mask : `name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1`, than image should be clickable, otherwise image should not be clickable, is it possible ?

Comment: @vickeycolors yes, but you have to check this condition before click event

Comment: @vickeycolors you can add one more extra attribute with value masked to image and check if clicked image is masked or not

Answer (score 0):

as you said Mask image name starts with **mask_** so u can search for this if it found in the name @0 location then can do ...

```
if (layer.name.search("mask_") == 0) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, usually it will be like `mask_image_1 , mask_image_2 , mask_pic_1 , mask_pic_2`

Comment: I updated your code here: https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/gEEPjQ , but i dont see any results, did i done something wrong ?